# What is the best way to prevent Access database bloat

Tags: ms-access, database-design, vba

**Intro:**

I am creating a Access database system that will be rolled out with multi-user functionality. 
But as i am creating this database in Access 2000 (Old school I know) there are quite a lot of bugs and random mysterious problems that occur when my database gets passed 40-60MB.

**My question:**

Has anyone got a good solution to how I can shrink this down or to prevent the bloat?

**Details:**

I am using many local tables combined with SQL Tables and my front-end links to a back-end SQL Server.
I have already tried compact and repair but it only ever shrinks it to about 15MB and after the user has used the database a few time the bloat expands quickly to over 50-60MB!

Let me know if more detail is needed but that is the rough outline of my problem.

Many Thanks!

Comment: You *do* know that Microsoft stopped supporting Office 2000 products more than 3.5 years ago, right? If you are having problems with "bugs and random mysterious problems" then continuing to use outdated software might not be the best way to go.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a newer version of Access?  I still use an application that was first coded in Access 1.0 in 1993.  I upgrade it to new office versions as they come out and it only very rarely breaks anything.  If something does break, it's usually pretty easy to fix it.  Buying a new Access license is probably cheaper than all of the care and maintenance that a big Access 2000 database would need.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I completely agree with you both that upgrading is certainly the way forward but the company is stuck with legacy systems and many intricate integrations with the current Access system we have in place therefore upgrading would not be idea at this point in time for us. So I am just trying to get the best out of Access 2000.
We are currently rewriting and testing the new changes that would be implicated if we did upgrade our systems but there is a lot of code to check through!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some ideas for you to follow.

You said you also have a lot of local tables. Split the local tables off into yet another Access database. So you'll have 2 back-ends (1 SQL Server & 1 Access), and the front end.

Create a batch file that opens your local tables backend database with the **/compact** option. So, it will look something like this:

```
"C:\Prog...\Microsoft...\Officexx\ C:\ProjectX_backend.mdb /compact"
```

Then run this batch file on a daily basis using scheduled tasks. Your frontend should never need compacting unless you edit it in any way.

Comment: I tried this method out and it's perfect for what I want! The bloat is not contained within the local back-end so to speak and keeps the front-end fresh and un-bloated! Appreciate the idea Tom! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with 2000, which has a quite bad reputation, then you have to dig down into your application and find out what creates the bloat. The most common reason are bulk inserts followed by deletes. Other reasons, are the use of OLE Object fields. Other reasons are programmatic changes in in form, etc objects. You really have to go through your application and find the specific cause.

An mdb file that is only connected to a backed server and does not make changes to local objects should not grow.

As for your random issues, besides some lack of stability in the 2000 version, you should look into bad RAM in the computers, bad hard drives, and broken network controllers if your mdb file is shared on the network.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will looking to these potential issues that may be causing significant system bloat. The computers may have a part to play since we are still running on XP on some machines which can limit the available RAM that can be used due to XPs limitations! I shall report back when I have tried and tested some of these ideas.